# Creating a connection to a WCF application

Tags: wcf

Good time of day. I would like to know how to properly connect in a WCF application. In other words, it should be created when the app is launched and be active throughout the entire operation? Or do you need to create a connection every time a service function is called? Now I have the first option, but somewhere everything is fine, and sometimes for unknown reasons I get an error: it is Impossible to use the object for communication, since it is in the failed state. There are no visible reasons for this - the code runs without errors. NetTcpBinding is used as the binding

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The wcf service needs to be hosted in the process so that the client can connect to the server. As long as you are using the wcf service, you need to enable it. Faulted state means there has been an unexpected exception on the server side, so you need to use a try…catch  block. Another possibility is that the channel has expired. The default timeout period of the WCF service is 10 minutes. If the client does not communicate with the server within 10 minutes, the channel will be closed. You need to recreate the channel to call the service.